# How to perform **manual sync**?

Tags: libp2p, network, sync

Substrate automatically syncs up upon starting and supports `--sync <SYNC_MODE>` `full`, `fast,` `fast-unsafe` and `wrap`
However, I'd like to have `manual` to prevent the node from synchronizing when starting the node for my specific reason to do so...

Here's my naive idea to make sync configurable:

1. Add **SyncMode::Manual**

```
if self.mode == SyncMode::Manual { // stop peers connection }
```

2. Add rpc `sync` command -> synchronize the node, downloading the blocks manually, once getting the best block or target block hash, then stop it.

Is that doable??
Much appreciated for any advice and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is currently doable like you described.
You can abuse the `--in-peers` and `--out-peers` flags and set them to `0` to not sync your node.
Then you have to restart it once you want it to sync without the flags. Not quite what you asked for, but at least close.